# How do I send a window to the back (lower it) in GNOME Shell?

Tags: centos, window-manager, gnome-shell

Most window managers let you send a window to the back.  For example, in MS Windows, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.  In `twm` (and the like), you can configure it.  In `fvwm2` it's called the "lower" function.

How do I do this with GNOME Shell (on CentOS 8)?

This assumes that I've correctly identified GNOME Shell as the window manager.  If it's not, where do I get this necessary functionality?

Comment: Are you looking for `Windows-key + H`  ?

Comment: Note: MS-Windows does not have a go-to-back. However in **some** situations alt-ESC works, some times. I did write a windows-hot-keys macro that worked most of the time back in 2002ish.

Comment: WindowsKey + H "iconifies" the window.  So, no.  I was hoping to send it to the back.  The opposite of bring window to front.

Comment: On Windows 7, I use alt-esc hundreds of times per hour, and I've never had it fail.  Ever.  So, I don't know where or if it's documented (I heard about it on StackExchange), but I can say that it works reliably for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is disabled by default but a hotkey can be assigned here:

**Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> View and Customize Shortcuts -> Windows -> Lower window below other windows**

Comment: I'm running CentOS 8 Stream with Xorg (not Wayland) and GDM, so it was mildly different, but I got to it within minutes.  You are a god!

-E

Answer (score 1):

If you have "tweaks" installed do:: tweaks | windows | titlebar actions ---> can set either double-click or middle-click or secondary-click to "lower" the clicked-upon window

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).